# AutoIncrement in SQLite with Subsonic 3

Tags: subsonic

This is probably a simple matter, but when I create a new object, the ID property starts off as 0 rather than null. As I understand it, SQLite takes/needs a value of null for the PK column to do the AutoIncrement.

So the short question is how to get the ID in the object to start life as null?

Thanks
cooter

Comment: What happens if you call .Save() on the new object?  Does the property/field in the object corresponding to the PK column get an auto-incremented value?  What if you set the PK property to null before you call .Save()?

Comment: If I call .Save() and there is already a record with ID 0 then I get an exception about needing unique values. I can't set the column to null as it is a property and you cant set int to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what the solution seems to be. After you create the tables with PK's, open the table, right click on the left most column where the key image is and you can choose to edit Keys/Relationships. In that property screen you can set the column to auto-increment.

I also followed advice on [this page](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2009/11/playing-with-sqlite-subsonic3-and-repository-mode/).

This is all done using the most excellent tools from sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

-Cooter